# Can I send multiple dwellers out together?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a good group of dwellers and I was wondering this if I send a group of dwellers together. If so, how?

Comment: Only on quests.

Answer (score 4):

You need to build the [Overseer's office](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overseer%27s_office). (unlocks after 18 dwellers)
This allows you to send out quests, which is 1-3 dwellers together, they go and do missions.

I do not think you can do it from just dragging them together.

Comment: Correct, if you drag them out together, they will just go individually into the wasteland, and will not be able to help each other in firefights/encounters/etc.